# Data Protection key not found in key ring - Console Application

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, console

I am currently working on a .net core 6 console application that needs to make use of Data Protection Protect/UnProtect.

I am persisting keys to the database and everything works fine locally. When I deploy my code using devops up to my server I get this message when attempting to call the Protect/Unprotect methods: "The key {0e9bdaff-9f8c-40ba-bd0a-c2cf5a2e3ade} was not found in the key ring".

My Implementation looks like this:

**Program.cs**

```
        services.AddScoped<IDataProtectionService, DataProtectionService>();
        services.AddDbContext<KeysContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(config.GetConnectionString("MyConnection")));
        services.AddDataProtection()
            .SetApplicationName("MyApplicationName")
            .PersistKeysToDbContext<KeysContext>();
```

**DataProtectionService.cs**

```
 public class DataProtectionService : IDataProtectionService
{
    private readonly ILogger<DataProtectionService> _logger;
    private readonly IDataProtector _dataProtector;
    public DataProtectionService(IDataProtectionProvider protectionProvider, ILogger<DataProtectionService> logger)
    {
        _dataProtector = protectionProvider.CreateProtector("MyApplicationName");
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public string Encrypt(string value)
    {
        try
        {
          return  _dataProtector.Protect(value);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _logger.LogError(e,"Error Encrypting Value ");
            return "";
        }
    }


    public string Decrypt(string value)
    {
        try
        {
            return _dataProtector.Unprotect(value);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _logger.LogError(e, "Error Decrypting Value ");
            return "";
        }
    }
}

public interface IDataProtectionService
{
    string Encrypt(string value);
    string Decrypt(string value);

}
```

**Consuming Class**

I am using DI and reference the interface

```
    private readonly IDataProtectionService _dataProtector;
```

and then hook it up in the constructor

```
    public MyService(IDataProtectionService dataProtector)
    {
        _dataProtector = dataProtector;
    }
```

Then I call the method like this:

```
        var myValue = _dataProtector.Decrypt(myProtectedValue);
```

When I call the decrypt method I can see the there has been an entry made in to my DataProtectionKeys table in the database with a friendly name and XML as one might expect. In the error log the GUID specified as the missing key does not match any value in the DataProtectionKeys table.

The console app itself is being run from windows task scheduler running under my user account with highest privileges.

Can anyone help with what might be wrong here?

Comment: Inside the database, did the MyApplicationName is right or not? Is the application using the same database as your locally test?